# SimpleXML, XPath: how to get content of element by unique id?

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml

kept trying for hours, brain messed up, need help:

XML-file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testresult>
  <body>
    <itemset name="sc">
      <item name="1">1</item>
      <item name="2">3</item>
      <item name="3">0</item>
    </itemset>
  </body>
</testresult>
```

Now I want to retrieve the content (`0`) of the item with the unique name "3" into `$value` ...

```
$value = $resultxml->xpath("//item[@name='$name']");
```

unfortunately not... what do I need to do to have `$value` to contain `0`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$results = $xml->xpath("//item[@name='$name']");
$value = (int)$results[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the content of the element, you could just cast it to string.

In your case, if you want to get `'0'`, then try:

```
var_dump((string)$value[0]);
```